# How to restart redis cluster node after failure

Tags: redis

I am experimenting with Redis Cluster as per document. I have small confusion.

Initial Configuration

```
35edd8052caf37149b4f9cc800fcd2ba60018ab5 127.0.0.1:30005@40005 slave bd76f831d34ed265a964e5f5caff2c0807c96b85 0 1524390407263 5 connected
d9e92c606f1fddebf84bbbc6f76485e418647683 127.0.0.1:30003@40003 master - 0 1524390407263 8 connected 10923-16383
edf62838d10b99018a0ecb7698c1b9ac52aa3bbb 127.0.0.1:30002@40002 myself,master - 0 1524390407000 2 connected 5461-10922
bd76f831d34ed265a964e5f5caff2c0807c96b85 127.0.0.1:30001@40001 master - 0 1524390407062 1 connected 0-5460
55a72ea5b4d0a77e2b18ca2b3f74b20d3550244c 127.0.0.1:30006@40006 slave edf62838d10b99018a0ecb7698c1b9ac52aa3bbb 0 1524390407562 6 connected
26788ce4523c95a93bd63907c1c75827fe61476a 127.0.0.1:30004@40004 slave d9e92c606f1fddebf84bbbc6f76485e418647683 0 1524390407263 8 connected
```

Now to test that if any master get failed I failed it manually using following command.

```
redis-cli -p 30001 debug segfault
```

Now configuration is look like this. ( 30001 is failed and 30005 promoted as master)

```
35edd8052caf37149b4f9cc800fcd2ba60018ab5 127.0.0.1:30005@40005 master - 0 1524390694964 9 connected 0-5460
d9e92c606f1fddebf84bbbc6f76485e418647683 127.0.0.1:30003@40003 master - 0 1524390695064 8 connected 10923-16383
edf62838d10b99018a0ecb7698c1b9ac52aa3bbb 127.0.0.1:30002@40002 myself,master - 0 1524390694000 2 connected 5461-10922
bd76f831d34ed265a964e5f5caff2c0807c96b85 127.0.0.1:30001@40001 master,fail - 1524390636966 1524390636165 1 disconnected
55a72ea5b4d0a77e2b18ca2b3f74b20d3550244c 127.0.0.1:30006@40006 slave edf62838d10b99018a0ecb7698c1b9ac52aa3bbb 0 1524390694964 6 connected
26788ce4523c95a93bd63907c1c75827fe61476a 127.0.0.1:30004@40004 slave d9e92c606f1fddebf84bbbc6f76485e418647683 0 1524390695164 8 connected
```

How can I add 30001 again into cluster ? Also How can I start that node Only ?

I am following this document.
https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial. ( Here there is one statement that "I restarted the crashed instance so that it rejoins the cluster as a slave" but did not mention how to do that ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

creating a cluster using redis-trib.rb needs running instances of Redis which we should start using a custom config file

```
../redis-server redis.conf
```

where redis.conf contains config for that node.
For instance

- port 7000
- cluster-enabled yes
- cluster-config-file nodes.conf
- cluster-node-timeout 5000
- appendonly yes

The redis cluster is created as below,

```
./redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 host1:port1 host2:port2 host3:port3 host4:port4 host5:port5 host6:port6
```

The ruby file will randomly create master and slaves among these and create a nodes.conf file (as mentioned in redis.conf file) which will have the node information

when you start the server using ../redis-server redis.conf it will pick node information like id, its master/slave from nodes.conf and connect to cluster again

Comment: My problem is that only one redis server is stopped or failed so I want to start it again. where does nodes.conf file created.

Comment: if you have followed the redis cluster tutorial the nodes.conf is created inside the port named  folder ie 30001 in your case

Comment: @dotnetstep if you are satisfied with the answer. kindly accept it to help the community

Comment: did not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can restart the redis instance on required port, using the same command as you have used to start it earlier i.e.

```
cd 30001
../redis-server redis.conf
```

Comment: I know that to start redis we have to do that but I have used redis-trib.rb to create cluster. In that case what is the location of redis.conf file . Right now your answer is more generic.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you followed the tutorial and created the cluster using `create-cluster` command i.e.

```
# pwd: redis/utils/create-cluster
./create-cluster start
./create-cluster create
```

To bring back the node that you failed, start it again using

```
./create-cluster start
```

This will start the failed node. Currently running nodes won't be affected.

https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/utils/create-cluster/create-cluster#L25